# How to get a list of TestReports at the end of a py.test run?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to get a list of all tests (e.g. in the form of a py.test TestReport) at the end of all tests.

I know that `pytest_runtest_makereport`does something similar, but only for a single test. But I want to implement a hook or something in `conftest.py` to process the whole list of tests before the `py.test` application terminates.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to print a list of all tests in the terminal or output it to an xml file?

Comment: Neither. I want a method like `pytest_runtest_makereport`to process the list of results. I might want to print out something, but in the way I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here an example which can help you. Structure of files:

```
/example:
   __init__.py  # empty file
   /test_pack_1
      __init__.py # empty file
      conftest.py # pytest hooks
      test_my.py  # a few tests for demonstration
```

There are 2 tests in `test_my.py`:

```
def test_one():
    assert 1 == 1
    print('1==1')


def test_two():
    assert 1 == 2
    print('1!=2')
```

Example of `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.runner import TestReport
from _pytest.terminal import TerminalReporter


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter):  # type: (TerminalReporter) -> generator
    yield
    # you can do here anything - I just print report info
    print('*' * 8 + 'HERE CUSTOM LOGIC' + '*' * 8)

    for failed in terminalreporter.stats.get('failed', []):  # type: TestReport
        print('failed! node_id:%s, duration: %s, details: %s' % (failed.nodeid,
                                                                 failed.duration,
                                                                 str(failed.longrepr)))

    for passed in terminalreporter.stats.get('passed', []):  # type: TestReport
        print('passed! node_id:%s, duration: %s, details: %s' % (passed.nodeid,
                                                                 passed.duration,
                                                                 str(passed.longrepr)))
```

> [Documentation says](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_terminal_summary) that **pytest_terminal_summary** has **exitstatus** arg

Run tests without any additional options: `py.test ./example`. Example of output:

```
example/test_pack_1/test_my.py .F
********HERE CUSTOM LOGIC********
failed! node_id:test_pack_1/test_my.py::test_two, duration: 0.000385999679565, details: def test_two():
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

example/test_pack_1/test_my.py:7: AssertionError
passed! node_id:test_pack_1/test_my.py::test_one, duration: 0.00019907951355, details: None

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_two ___________________________________

    def test_two():
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

example/test_pack_1/test_my.py:7: AssertionError
====================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ======================
```

Hope this helps.

> Note! Make sure that .pyc files was removed before running tests

Comment: @Alex I was glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: @Alex nope. `pytest` expects that `hook` will return the generator

Comment: @CodeCollector I don't know. need to investigate.