# What does 'yield' return if no argument is given?

Tags: python

There are some examples of python functions that contains a `yield` - but without any parameter.

Examples: [here](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489844/what-does-yield-without-value-do-in-context-manager) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445609/how-to-get-a-list-of-testreports-at-the-end-of-a-py-test-run).

So what does that `yield` yield then? How does it work?

Comment: it returns None, the same as a Return with no parameter.

Comment: So I could just remove it?

Comment: No- a yield pauses the operation of a generator and returns control to the calling function. If there is no yield, the generator will continue to run to completion.

Comment: @Alex no, yield, will turn the function into a generator. I guess that's what is intended by the creators of those codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what does that `yield` yield then?

As [commented by Paul Becotte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506001/what-does-yield-return-if-no-argument-is-given/49506405#comment86015998_49506001) `yield` without a value yields `None`.

> How does it work?

From the [Python Generators wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), the `yield` syntax is the syntactic sugar that you need to tell Python to generate an iterable object from your function. It converts:

```
# a generator that yields items instead of returning a list
def firstn(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num += 1
```

into:

```
# Using the generator pattern (an iterable)
class firstn(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.num, self.nums = 0, []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    # Python 3 compatibility
    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        if self.num < self.n:
            cur, self.num = self.num, self.num+1
            return cur
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

> So I could just remove it? — [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506001/what-does-yield-return-if-no-argument-is-given/49506405#comment86016026_49506001)

Without the `yield` keyword it's just a function that returns `None`.

Carrying on further down in the wiki, there is a way that you can create iterators without the `yield` keyword. You use list comprehension syntax with `()`. So to carry on the rather trivial example (which is just `xrange`, the generator version of `range`):

```
def firstn(n):
    return (x for x in range(n))
```

> Alternately, we can think of list comprehensions as generator expressions wrapped in a list constructor.

```
>>> list(firstn(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to address the question, which as I understand it is asking about `yield` as a standalone statement (as opposed to e.g. `yield num`).

Comment: @DavidZ the OP asks *"How does it work"*, then further in the comments asks [*"can I just remove it?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506001/what-does-yield-return-if-no-argument-is-given/49506405#comment86016026_49506001). I'm explaining why you need the `yield` keyword. The answer to what is returned with no variable is already mentioned in the comments. I'll add it to remove any confusion.

Comment: The pytest package has [examples](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html) contain:

```
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
```

I don't understand this code ...but it works and `yield` is clearly returning something other than `None`.

Comment: Sorry, the code should read `outcome = yield` followed by `rep = outcome.get_result()` .